# retrofit.RetrofitError: com.google.gson.JsonSyntaxException: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Expected BEGIN_OBJECT but was STRING at line 1

Tags: android, gson, retrofit

I'm getting a very strange json as below and gson can not parse it in any way. I'm trying to catch it as list because it seems an array but always throws exception above

```
[{"Old":"1","New":"2","ConfirmNew":"2","Result":"succesfully completed","CustomProperties":{}},"eyJBY2Nlc3NUb2tlbiI6bnVsbCwiQ3VzdG9tZXJJRCI6NTc0Njc1LCJMYXN0QWNjZXNzVGltZSI6IlwvRGF0ZSgxNDQ3MzcyMjY3NjgxKVwvIiwiU2Vzc2lvbkd1aWQiOiIwZTkyNTY0YS05NzI1LTQ2MWEtOTMyYS03OTczZmMyYWJhN2QifQ=="]
```

Here the class which I'm trying to parse

```
@Getter
@Setter
@Accessors(fluent = true)
public class ChangePasswordResponseEntity {


@Expose
@SerializedName("Old")
private String Old;
@Expose
@SerializedName("New")
private String New;
@Expose
@SerializedName("ConfirmNew")
private String ConfirmNew;
@Expose
@SerializedName("Result")
private String Result;
@Expose
@SerializedName("CustomProperties")
private CustomProperties CustomProperties;
}
```

and retrofit side

```
@POST("/ChangePassword/")
    Observable<List<ChangePasswordResponseEntity>> changePassword(
            @Body ChangePasswordRequestEntity changePasswordRequestEntity,
            @Query(value = "signedRequest", encodeValue = false) String sessionID);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can you a custom [`TypeAdapterFactory`](https://google-gson.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/gson/docs/javadocs/com/google/gson/TypeAdapterFactory.html).  To grab the first element of the array and discard the rest.

```
public class PasswordResponseAdapterFactory implements TypeAdapterFactory {
  @Override
  public <T> TypeAdapter<T> create(Gson gson, TypeToken<T> typeToken) {
    if (typeToken.getType() != ChangePasswordResponseEntity.class) {
      return null;
    }
    return (TypeAdapter<T>) newPasswordResponseAdapter(gson.getDelegateAdapter(this, TypeToken.get(ChangePasswordResponseEntity.class)));
  }

  private  TypeAdapter<ChangePasswordResponseEntity> newPasswordResponseAdapter (final TypeAdapter<ChangePasswordResponseEntity> delegateAdapter) {
    return new TypeAdapter<ChangePasswordResponseEntity>() {

      @Override
      public void write(JsonWriter out, ChangePasswordResponseEntity value) throws IOException {
        delegateAdapter.write(out, value);
      }

      @Override
      public ChangePasswordResponseEntity read(JsonReader in) throws IOException {
        in.beginArray();
        ChangePasswordResponseEntity response = delegateAdapter.read(in);
        while(in.hasNext()) {
          // Skip remaining elements in the array
          in.skipValue();
        }
        in.endArray();
        return response;
      }
    };
  }
}
```

Change your interface to look for just `ChangePasswordResponseEntity` --

```
@POST("/ChangePassword/")
    Observable<ChangePasswordResponseEntity> changePassword(
            @Body ChangePasswordRequestEntity changePasswordRequestEntity,
            @Query(value = "signedRequest", encodeValue = false) String sessionID);
```

Make a custom gson with your factory --

```
Gson gson = new GsonBuilder()
    .registerTypeAdapterFactory(new PasswordResponseAdapterFactory())
    .create();
```

Use your new gson when you create your `GsonConverterFactory`.

```
Retrofit retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
    .baseUrl("http://www.example.com/")
    .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create(gson))
    // other settings ...
    .build();
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems you truncated the error message just where it got interesting, namely the character position in line 1 where to parsing fails. My guess is that the position is 96+-1.

```
[
    {
        "Old": "1",
        "New": "2",
        "ConfirmNew": "2",
        "Result": "succesfully completed",
        "CustomProperties": {}
    },
    "eyJBY2Nlc3NUb2tlbiI6bnVsbCwiQ3VzdG9tZXJJRCI6NTc0Njc1LCJMYXN0QWNjZXNzVGltZSI6IlwvRGF0ZSgxNDQ3MzcyMjY3NjgxKVwvIiwiU2Vzc2lvbkd1aWQiOiIwZTkyNTY0YS05NzI1LTQ2MWEtOTMyYS03OTczZmMyYWJhN2QifQ=="
]
```

I suppose the parsing fails not because of the first element, which is indeed an Object and does fit your `ChangePasswordResponseEntity`, but because of the second element, which is a String.

Comment: yes I think so but I dont have any chance to edit json. I just need that "result" parameter actually, need to find a way to get it! :(